# How to modify the modification to an array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, for-loop, index-error

I am trying to modify the arrayEndValue to where the modified array items that is returned will be added by 10. I have tried everything within my knowledge, and I keep getting different error codes. The most common one is IndexError: list index out of range. I would like some help understanding where I am going wrong. The last for loop is mine.

```
array = []
inputTotal = int(input("Number of items for the array (must be at least 5): "))
if inputTotal >= 5:
    for arrayItem in range(inputTotal):
        arrayInputs = int(input(f"Input  {arrayItem + 1}: "))
        array.append(arrayInputs)

    for arrayItem in range(len(array)):
        array[arrayItem] = array[arrayItem] * 5
    print("\nModified array items: ", end="")

    for arrayEndValue in array:
        print(arrayEndValue, end='')

# modification to the modified array
    array2 = [arrayEndValue]
    for modiedArray in array2:
        array2[modiedArray] = array2[arrayEndValue] + 10
    print(modiedArray, end='')

else:
    print("Number must be at least 5")
```

Comment: FYI, these are lists, not arrays.

Comment: Are you trying to make a copy of `array` into `array2`? Use `array2 = array.copy()`

Comment: The last `for` loop makes no sense. `modiedArray` and `arrayEndValue` aren't indexes. `modiedArray` contains the elements of `array2`, and `arrayEndValue` is the last element of `array`.

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do, so it's hard to write a real answer.

Comment: I started figuring that part out as I was looking over it again. overall, I am trying to add 10 to the printed arrayEndValue numbers.

Comment: Then do it the same way that you multiplied by 5 earlier.